# Help please on unit circle question

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

could someone please look at the pic and help me with this unit circle question? Would the correct answer be pi/8, 3pi/8, 5pi/8, and 7pi/8? I'm not sure..... Please help!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What pic?

Comment: Oops! This is my first time on the website so I'm not familiar with the operations. The picture is here-https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4LAv.png

Comment: Recall that a full circle is $2\pi$.  Recall that pointed straight right corresponds to an angle of zero, straight left an angle of $\pi$, half of that, pointed straight up is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.  $P$ appears to be (*and in fact is*) halfway between $0$ and $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$... so no, $\dfrac{\pi}{8}$ is wrong.  Now... what are the other points where it has this?  Well... $\dfrac{\pi}{8}$ is a sixteenth of the way around the circle, $\dfrac{3\pi}{8}$ is three sixteenths of the way around the circle, $\dfrac{5\pi}{8}$ is five sixteenths of the way around the circle etc... they aren't pointed @ $P$

Comment: So... the next times it hits the point $P$... it will have gone *all the way around the circle and then a bit more*...

Answer (score 2):

Try to think about how a terminal point is defined, and drawing the angles you have mentioned onto the diagram.